# Hangfire Recurring Job working Intermittently

Tags: .net, hangfire, hangfire-sql

I have an API that's using .Net Framework 4.7, Hangfire (v1.7.11). I have the Recurring Job to run daily at 3am using cron expression "0 3 * * *". But the Recurring Job is running Intermittently and shows the Next Execution as past "Next Execution - 7 hrs ago". Need some help with resolving this issue due to tight timelines for our upcoming release. Also went through setting up everything as per the link below:
https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Documentation/blob/master/deployment-to-production/making-aspnet-app-always-running.rst

[My Hangfire Dashboard Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dP8jk.png)

Comment: What version of hangfire are you running? Can you also confirm all servers are running the same version? Have you tried the latest release to see if that resolves your problem? (Latest I believe is 1.7.11 as of today)

Comment: I am using the 1.7.11 version. This is a nuget package so the version being used in the API will be the same version across different environments.

Comment: Can you share the command you used to create the Hangfire Job ?